# Compare any number of dates in list inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, date, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dates like this (The keys here are relevant to some other work and need to be considered):

```
{2: ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012', '7-12-2012],
 5: ['10-12-2012', '11-12-2012'],
 7: ['13-12-2012']}
```

Now, I want to find the earliest date in each list.  In the end, I need to find out which date out of all was the earliest, returning that date and the key.

**If I manually go through what I'm trying to do here:**

```
**key 2**, `7-12-2012` is the earliest.
**key 5**, `10-12-2012` is the earliest.
**key 7**, `13-12-2012` is the earliest.
```

7-12-2012 is the earliest date, so I should return `2`.

**Things to note here:**

1. The data in the dictionary are created dynamically during runtime.
2. the lists inside the dictionary is not fixed length.

This is what I tried but only compares two dates:

```
...
...
# this value would be dynamically set during runtime
expiryDates[item] = {2: ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012', '7-12-2012], 5: ['10-12-2012', '11-12-2012'], 7: ['13-12-2012']}

datesInBox = []
dict_earliest_expiration = defaultdict(list)

for n in expiryDates:
    datesInBox = expiryDates[n] # when n = 2; datesInBox = ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012']
    d1 = time.strptime(datesInBox[0], "%d-%m-%Y")
    d2 = time.strptime(datesInBox[1], "%d-%m-%Y")
    if d1 < d2:
        dict_earliest_expiration[n] = d1
    else:
        dict_earliest_expiration[n] = d2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform all strings to date and then use the [min](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#min) function:

```
import time

data = {2: ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012', '7-12-2012'], 5: ['10-12-2012', '11-12-2012'], 7: ['13-12-2012']}
d2 = {k: [time.strptime(e, "%d-%m-%Y") for e in v] for k, v in data.items()}
print(min(d2, key=lambda e: min(d2[e])))
```

**Output**

```
2
```

As an alternative you could precompute the min for each key of the dictionary:

```
data = {2: ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012', '7-12-2012'], 5: ['10-12-2012', '11-12-2012'], 7: ['13-12-2012']}
d2 = {k: min(time.strptime(e, "%d-%m-%Y") for e in v) for k, v in data.items()}
print(min(d2, key=lambda e: d2[e]))
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Finally instead of iterating over the keys you could iterate over the key, value pairs:

```
data = {2: ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012', '7-12-2012'], 5: ['10-12-2012', '11-12-2012'], 7: ['13-12-2012']}
d2 = {k: min(time.strptime(e, "%d-%m-%Y") for e in v) for k, v in data.items()}
print(min(d2.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])[0])
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through your dict or pass the key directly. Convert the list to pandas series and sort it

```
import pandas as pd
d={2: ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012', '7-12-2012'], 5: ['10-12-2012', '11-12-2012'], 7: ['13-12-2012']}

for key,value in d.items():
    print(key,pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(value)).sort_values().iloc[0])
```

Output

```
(2, Timestamp('2012-07-12 00:00:00'))
(5, Timestamp('2012-10-12 00:00:00'))
(7, Timestamp('2012-12-13 00:00:00'))
```

If you are just concerned with dates

```
for key,value in d.items():
    print(key,pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(value)).dt.date.sort_values().iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
(2, datetime.date(2012, 7, 12))
(5, datetime.date(2012, 10, 12))
(7, datetime.date(2012, 12, 13))
```

Representing the date in accordance to the example given

```
for key,value in d.items():
    print('key: {}, Earliest Date: {} '.format(key,pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(value)).dt.date.sort_values().iloc[0].strftime("%m-%d-%Y")))
```

Output:

```
key: 2, Earliest Date: 07-12-2012 
key: 5, Earliest Date: 10-12-2012 
key: 7, Earliest Date: 12-13-2012
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll work through this slowly, so you can see the process.  First, reverse the dict: use the time as the key, the former key as the value:

```
exp = {2: ['8-12-2012', '9-12-2012', '7-12-2012'], 5: ['10-12-2012', '11-12-2012'], 7: ['13-12-2012']}
rev = []

for key, val_list in exp.items():
    for val in val_list:
        rev[time.strptime(val, "%d-%m-%Y")] = key
```

Cleaning up the representation, `rev` is now

```
{
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=13): 7, 
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday= 8): 2, 
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday= 7): 2, 
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday= 9): 2, 
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=11): 5, 
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=10): 5
}
```

Now it's a simple matter of printing the key for the earliest time:

```
>>> rev[min(rev)]
2
```

If you like, you can collapse this into a dict comprehension and a trivial call.

Comment: I keep getting a "NameError: name 'rev' is not defined". Tried googling but no results. Was there something above the exp value?

Comment: I chopped off the initialization line.  My apologies.  Fixed now.